# not a valid HTTP header field value ajax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-headers

I'm developing some javascript code to use the [summon](http://api.summon.serialssolutions.com/) api server. I developed a simple js function to send a ajax request to the server using JQuery .ajax as below.

```
requestApi = function(currentDate, digest) {
  return $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://api.summon.serialssolutions.com/2.0.0/search",
    data: "s.q=cancer",
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/xml',
      'x-summon-date': currentDate,
      'Authorization': 'Summon myuser;' + digest
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      return console.log(status, err.message);
    }
  }).done(function(data) {
    return console.log(data);
  }).fail(function() {
    return console.log("Summon Ajax Failed!");
  });
};
```

but I faced an error like:

> Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 
>   'Summon myuser;CkKhLokX5jdOx8oCYhgn848MZfw=' 
>   is not a valid HTTP header field value.

I don't really know where the problem is. Guide me please. Thanks

Comment: Did you check cross-domain? Keyword jsonp?

Comment: If I add `dataType: 'jsonp'` the API server reply me a **401 Unauthorized** because the `digest` is a hashed string including GET parameters. Help me if I make something wrong @axel.michel

Comment: did you find out the answer?